# How to add new remote content to unity addressable without rebuilding and uploading app (android and IOS)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, addressables

I have a lot of content in unity addressable. I want to add more new content. The problem I'm facing is that when I use to update content for addressable and upload it to remote. the app doesn't fetch from the remote. I have to make an android/IOS build each time for new content to be added. Is there a workaround where I don't have to upload IOS/Android build each time new content is added?

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to implement some sort of server call that returns the version of the actual content.

Then you can check the version of the content in the app, and if it does not match - download the newer one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create New Addressable Groups using 'Check for Content Update Restrictions'
2. Update Bundle Data & Build Update using 'Update previous build'
3. Upload New Bundle Files After Addressable build